# How to include the calling class and line number in the log using Pantheios?

Tags: c++, logging, pantheios

I just started using [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/) and it feels really like a great library for logging! Maybe even the greatest one for C++! Congratulations to the author!

However, I could not find neither in the documentation nor in all the forum posts anything about how to include the calling class and the line number in the log.

I'm using **be.file** as back end and I defined custom front end, looking at the example of **fe.simple**. Is this something to do with the `PANTHEIOS_EXTERN_C const char PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY[]` or I'm on a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer for this actually is in the FAQ file included in the library download. I have a fixed-back-end DLL that has the following header in it and I am able to include the class, function and line number in the log file.

```
#include <pantheios/pantheios.hpp>
#include <pantheios/frontends/fe.N.h>
//#include <pantheios/frontends/fe.simple.h>
#ifndef PANTHEIOS_INCL_PANTHEIOS_H_TRACE
#define PANTHEIOS_TRACE_PREFIX         __FILE__ "(" PANTHEIOS_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "): " __FUNCTION__ ": "
#endif /* PANTHEIOS_INCL_PANTHEIOS_H_TRACE */
#include <pantheios/trace.h>
#include <pantheios/inserters.hpp>
#include <pantheios/backends/bec.file.h>    // be.file header
```

What is happening here is that you have to redefine PANTHEIOS_TRACE_PREFIX before including trace.h, which is what I have shown above. The other lines of code are included simply to show you where the #define goes. And sorry for the delayed response. If you wish I could post a download on my blog with a fixed-back-end DLL project that anyone could use in their solution for simple file-based logging. Leave a comment if you have any interest in that project

Update 2/28/2010 12:53 AM CST: For your reference here is the question from the FAQ:

Q9: "Does Pantheios provide a configuration that yields a logged message
     containing the containing function, equivalent to:

```
   log(informational, __FUNCTION__, ": my message");
```

without having to write that (or some wrapper that checks for compiler support)."   [15th March 2008]

A9:
  You need to #define PANTHEIOS_TRACE_PREFIX to what you want. By default
  it is `__FILE__ "(" PANTHEIOS_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "): "`, which gives the
  format `<file>(<line>):`

To include the function, lets says you want it to have the format `<file>(<line>): <func>:`. To achieve this you'd define it as follows:

```
#include <pantheios/pantheios.h>
#define PANTHEIOS_TRACE_PREFIX         __FILE__ " " PANTHEIOS_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ": " __FUNCTION__ ": "
#include <pantheios/trace.h>
```

Note that the definition *must* come before the inclusion of pantheios/trace.h. Therefore, a safer way of doing this is as follows:

```
/* File: myPantheiosRootHeader.h */
#include <pantheios/pantheios.h>

#ifdef PANTHEIOS_INCL_PANTHEIOS_H_TRACE
# error pantheios/trace.h must not be included before myPantheiosRootHeader.h
#endif /* PANTHEIOS_INCL_PANTHEIOS_H_TRACE */

#define PANTHEIOS_TRACE_PREFIX         __FILE__ " " PANTHEIOS_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ": " __FUNCTION__ ": "
#include <pantheios/trace.h>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder how did I missed this in the FAQ... :)
I also did everything in a DLL and it would be interesting to see how similar is it with your project.

Comment: Just one more comment: I was using methods instead of macros and the log always contained my wrapper method as caller. In order this to work, everything should be a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to include that information automatically - you can of course add the line number to the log message itself if you're using the __LINE__ macro. Not sure how portable this is, though.